# skipping frame issue (OpenCv)

Tags: opencv, video-capture

I am trying to play video on opencv. However, the program just shows the last frame of the video. Could anyone tell me why this is the case? Below is my code.

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>           // it may be necessary to change or remove this line if not using Windows
```

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(void) {

```
cv::VideoCapture capVideo; /*add a video capture object*/

cv::Mat imgFrame; /*add  a picture object to capture each frame*/

capVideo.open("768x576.avi"); /*open the video*/

if (!capVideo.isOpened()) {                                                 // if unable to open video file
    std::cout << "\nerror reading video file" << std::endl << std::endl;      // show error message
    _getch();                    // it may be necessary to change or remove this line if not using Windows
    return(0);                                                              // and exit program
}

/*this shows the number of frame will be given*/
if (capVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) < 1) {
    std::cout << "\nerror: video file must have at least one frame";
    _getch();
    return(0);
}

/*printing out the number of frame*/
cout<<"the number of frame:" << capVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) << endl;


char* videoTitle = "this is displaying the video";
cv::namedWindow(videoTitle, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
capVideo.read(imgFrame); // it will return a boolean value
int i = 0;
while (1)
{
    if (capVideo.read(imgFrame) == false)
    {
        break;
    }
    imshow(videoTitle, imgFrame);
    //it read every frame of the video

    i++;
    cout << "Frame Number: " << i << endl;  
}
cout << "End of the video" << endl;

waitKey(0);
return(0);
```

}

Comment: You're not calling `waitKey` after you update the window using `imshow`, so there's nothing pumping the messages for the GUI to work. Read the documentation. [\[1\]](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) [\[2\]](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7), especially the highlighted notes. (e.g. the part that says "This function is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and handle events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event processing ...").

Comment: That makes sense, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I will modify the while loop as follows.

```
while (capVideo.isOpened() && chCheckForEscKey != 27) {

        imshow("imgFrame", imgFrame);// now we prepare for the next iteration

        if ((capVideo.get(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) + 1) < capVideo.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) {       // if there is at least one more frame
            capVideo.read(imgFrame);                            // read it
        }
        else {                                                  // else
            cout << "end of video\n";                      // show end of video message
            break;                                              // and jump out of while loop
        }

        chCheckForEscKey = waitKey(1);      // get key press in case user pressed esc

    }

    if (chCheckForEscKey != 27) {               // if the user did not press esc (i.e. we reached the end of the video)
        waitKey(0);                         // hold the windows open to allow the "end of video" message to show
    }
    // note that if the user did press esc, we don't need to hold the windows open, we can simply let the program end which will close the windows

    return(0);
}
```